# Firebase deploy error: "malloc: can't allocate region" or "Segmentation fault: 11"

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an angular app and I am trying to deploy it to my Firebase hosting.

I keep getting this error:

```
node(2216,0x10c6afdc0) malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=9494189756595048448) failed (error code=3)
node(2216,0x10c6afdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
Abort trap: 6
```

or

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I am using Visual Studio Code on a Mac.
These are some of the libraries I am using:

- Angular CLI: 8.3.18
- Node: 12.13.1
- Angular: 8.2.13
- @angular/cli:8.3.18
- @angular/fire: 5.3.0-rc.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had as similar problem and solved it by updating `firebase-tools`.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```